# Discord bot sends message in the wrong order despite async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, discord.js

I'm having this asynchronous coding problem once again, so annoying. I want to avoid using the callback hell and avoid startig with `new Promise` and resolve so I use `async/await` instead.

**Objective**
I want my discord bot to spit out each server status, one after another in a channel, in the same order as defined.

**Issue**
Of course, the output is in the wrong order. I know that the speed of each server response is different. Despite using `async/await` it still doesn't work as I wanted and it confuses me. Looks like I'm using it wrong, just don't know where. I tried to iterate the array with a `forEach` loop and used `Promise.all()` but it's still not the correct order.

**My Code (MCVE)**
I am using the module [net](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_net) in order to request the server status and for this MCVE I took 3 random hosts instead.

```
const 
    status = require('net'),
    hosts = [
        ['Server #1', 'google.com', 80], 
        ['Server #2', 'jhfg87ed4.com', 80], // fake, just for response check
        ['Server #3', 'stackoverflow.com', 80]
    ]

const server = async (id, cb)=> {
    let host = hosts[id]
    const sock = new status.Socket()
    sock.setTimeout(2500)
    sock.on('connect', ()=> {
        cb(host[0]+': Up.')
        sock.destroy()
    }).on('error', e=> {
        cb(host[0]+': Down: '+e.message)
    }).on('timeout', e=> {
        cb(host[0]+' Down: timeout')
    }).connect(host[2], host[1])
}

async function results() { // wrong ?
    await server(0, cb => channel.send(cb))
    await server(1, cb => channel.send(cb))
    await server(2, cb => channel.send(cb))
}
```

**Output:** (random order)

```
results() // not the order I wanted

Server #3: Up.
Server #1: Up.
Server #2: Down: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND jhfg87ed4.com
```

**Workaround (bad practice)**

```
server(0, cb => {
    channel.send(cb)
    server(1, cb => {
        channel.send(cb)
        server(2, cb => {
            channel.send(cb)
        })
    })
})
```

Using this workaround fixes it and works like a charm but I want to avoid this callback hell as it's obviously bad practice.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: `server()` doesn't return a promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few errors in the script:

- `async` without calling `await` is not usefull
- usually a callback is used in place of `await`, you can't use both
- the universal callback interface is `callback(error, data)`, so you should follow this pattern

So your script should update as follow.

Note that this is a quick solution that doesn't manage errors! (aka `error` events)

```js
const status = require('net')
const util = require('util')

const hosts = [
  ['Server #1', 'google.com', 80],
  ['Server #2', 'jhfg87ed4.com', 80], // fake, just for response check
  ['Server #3', 'stackoverflow.com', 80]
]

function server (id, cb) {
  const host = hosts[id]
  const sock = new status.Socket()
  sock.setTimeout(2500)
  sock
    .on('connect', () => {
      cb(null, host[0] + ': Up.') // null as first parameter that is error
      sock.destroy()
    })
    .on('error', e => {
      cb(new Error(host[0] + ': Down: ' + e.message))
    })
    .on('timeout', e => {
      cb(new Error(host[0] + ' Down: timeout'))
    })
    .connect(host[2], host[1])
}

const serverPromise = util.promisify(server)

async function results () {
  let res = await serverPromise(0)
  console.log(res)
  try {
    res = await serverPromise(1)
    console.log(res)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  res = await serverPromise(2)
  console.log(res)
}

results()
```

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply. Thank you very much I already fixed it somehow. Yeah forgot about the `(error, data)` pattern for the callback, I didn't think of that. Still thanks a lot for your answer and the hints.